# Получить значение объекта

Tags: php

Добрый день, с php работал очень мало, по этому вопрос может показаться глупым. Сделал дамп переменной $res, выдало следующий результат:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (4) { ["result"]=> string(5) "error" ["status"]=> string(5) "error" ["err_code"]=> string(17) "payment_not_found" ["err_description"]=> string(30) "Платеж не найден" }
```

Мне необходимо получить status, как мне правильно это сделать?

Comment: получить свойство $res->status

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $res->status;
```

И так:

```
if ($res->status == "error") {
    // ошибка
}
```